# Highly available Oauth2 reverse proxy?

Tags: oauth-2.0, reverse-proxy, high-availability

Is an Oauth2 reverse proxy server expected to be HA or a single
    point of entry to a set of backend servers?

I have a load balancer balancing between two oauth2 reverse proxies each upstreaming to a grafana server.
Now the issue is that the grafana homepage doesn't load until some refreshes on the page.

On checking the logs, I have a few observations:

- Firstly, on hitting the URL, both the Oauth2 proxies show requests (I am guessing this is because multiple requests are fired to load the homepage of grafana)
- One of the proxy's logs shows 404 requests until a couple of refreshes after which both show 200 and the grafana homepage loads successfully
- Until then, the grafana page does not load but just shows the grafana background solid page with no errors

Am I doing something wrong with the architecture here? How is it possible to have HA for Oauth2 proxies?

Comment: Smells like homework... but if not, I would suggest asking questions one at a time and adding some background on what problem you're trying to solve and what you discovered so far in terms of answers.

Comment: Thanks @Evert. Made some changes to the question to make it more specific.